# How to write Junit test case for executeUpdateNativeQuery() In java

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to write a test case for following method with out hitting actual DB or configuring in memory database

```
public void deleteExistingRecord( List<String> extSrcIds) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("extSourceIds", extSrcIds);
    String query = "DELETE FROM REG.EXT_ACTIONED_RECORD T WHERE EXT_SRC_ID in :extSourceIds";
    executeUpdateNativeQuery(query, params);
}
```

Comment: What is the code in `executeUpdateNativeQuery`? Are you testing whether `deleteExistingRecord` calls `executeUpdateNativeQuery` or `executeUpdateNativeQuery` performing the SQL operation?

Comment: i am testing , deleteExistingRecord calls executeUpdateNativeQuery or not.

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example for this. It is unclear what you want to test. By looking at the code you posted, the `executeUpdateNativeQuery` will always be called. May be you need to change the method's behavior so that it is testable to start with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a method is called, you have to create a mock. See the Mockito website for more details: https://site.mockito.org/